# MSSQL procedure to insert multiple values instead of one value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this MSSQL procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertCodeIfNotExist
    @Code nvarchar(32)
AS
  INSERT Codes (Code)
  SELECT @Code
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
            FROM Codes
            WHERE Code = @Code
          );
```

Which works well for me, but I would be better if I could have it work with like a 100 values and call this procedure for each value. Is that possible with mssql? Can I define like a `InsertManyCodesIfNotExist` and loop over hundreds of values there?

Comment: From where you are providing this `@Code`? Also it looks like you want to make sure that the `@Code` value is unique in your table so why don't you make it as a `UNIQUE` column?

Comment: @RahulTripathi I am using node.js mssql package, which defines input params like this https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#input

Comment: @RahulTripathi I do have a constraint on there, which I have defined like this: ALTER TABLE Codes ADD CONSTRAINT code UNIQUE(Code)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you could do this quite easily a couple different ways. One way I handle situations like this is to create a user defined data type such as the one I use below:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ModuleList] AS TABLE(
    [SubId] [varchar](12) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SubId] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
```

In your case, substitute 'Code' for SubId. Then you can create this type in T-SQL, populate it with codes and pass it as a parameter to your stored proc.

Your stored proc would be set up to take this parameter as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SomeStoredProc]
    @ModuleList ModuleList READONLY
AS
...
```

As then you can treat @ModuleList just like a table. In your case, a table of codes.

Comment: It wont hurt if you clarified in the answer that it is called a [Table-Valued Parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/bb510489.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define a table-valued parameter and pass a table to your stored procedure:

```
/* Create a table type. */ 
CREATE TYPE CodeTableType AS TABLE ( Code VARCHAR(32)); 
GO 

/* Create a procedure to receive data for the table-valued parameter. */ 
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertCodeIfNotExist
@TVP CodeTableType READONLY 
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON 
INSERT INTO Codes (Code) 
SELECT 
    Code
FROM  
    @TVP;
```

Details you can find here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.120).aspx